# Inkscape circle/ellipse/arc tool : reset shape?

Tags: inkscape, shapes

The circle/ellipse/arc tool works well, however, I am finding the tool is copying the last used circle somehow. I have previously tried editing the nodes, and fiddling until e.g. a circle looks perfect by eye. This will not do in the long run - is there something like a "reset" button, so a perfect circle is created?

I looked at the following for the circle/ellipse/arc tool, from the GUI menu :

```
Edit>Preferences>Shapes>Ellipse:
Style of new objects
[ ]Last used style
[ ]This tool's own style (... things ... )
```

... but eventually I return to editing the nodes / fiddling by eye, and then trying to keep that perfect-by-eye circle set. I figure I can't be the only one, and seems to be a case of me not understanding or missing a detail.

programs:
Inkscape 1.1.2
Ubuntu 22.04.1

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "perfect". Do you mean a full circle?  If so, there's a button for this in the Controls Bar along the top. [see example](https://imgur.com/kQuPKPc). If this works for you I can add it as an answer.

Comment: Ah - thank you, getting closer : https://inkscape.org/forums/tutorials/what-to-do-when-a-tool-stops-working/ ... especially "For the Ellipse tool, this button  [a sort of circle] makes the ellipse whole again.". I'm not seeing that icon - perhaps the Linux version 1.1.2 has it somewhere else... NO NO - I just found it - sort of dark, so hard to see - top horizontal tool bar, between the menu-y things and the measurement boxes!... and... YES - it works!

Comment: I've added an answer now with a little more detail.

Comment: Just another suggestion for you, the Inkscape official tutorials are a bit basic, also some are quite old and need updating.  It might be worthwhile looking for some beginner tutorials on Youtube.  A very good channel called *Logos by Nick* has many really good tutorials, from raw beginner to more advanced.

Comment: Another good Youtube channel with excellent tutorials is IronEcho Design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Inkscape you can reset the Ellipse tool back to making a full ellipse/circle by pressing this button shown in the Controls Bar along the top of the screen.

[image]

To see this button, you **must** have the object selected (if you want it to change your circle) and you **must** have the Ellipse tool selected. Note: this will only work with SVG Ellipse/Circle objects. If you have converted the object to paths, these tool options will no longer work for that object.

This button may look different depending on which Icon theme you are using. I am using the Multicolor icon theme. You can actually customize the colours of these multicolor icons to whatever you like. You can change the icon themes in *Edit > Preferences > Interface > Theming*. Note also that icons may be different in older/newer versions of Inkscape, or possibly even across different platforms.  I'm using Inkscape 1.2.2 on Windows.

[image]

This is how these buttons look with different icon themes

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this page is working :

https://inkscape.org/forums/tutorials/what-to-do-when-a-tool-stops-working/

especially "For the Ellipse tool, this button [see below] makes the ellipse whole again."

... there are four icons on the far right of the tool bar, that will display depending on whether the rectangle, ellipse, etc., are selected. HOWEVER, the *particularly_relevant* icons for ellipse (there are four), are rather dark on the dark theme (and light on the light theme), so perhaps one might overlook them.